# Elegant way to classify singularities of $\exp(\tan(1/z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

The function
$$ \exp\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) $$
obviously has a removable singularity at $z=\infty$ and a non-isolated singularity at $z = 0$.

From the real $\tan(x)$ it is clear, that the singularities at
$$z_k = \frac{2}{(2k + 1)\pi} \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})$$
must be essential. Is there an quick and elegant way to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $w=1/z$ and
$$
\exp(\tan(1/z))
=
\exp(\tan(w))
=
\exp(\tan(w))
$$
Now set
$$
k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-w=u
$$
so that the expression becomes
$$
\exp(\cot u)
$$
When $z\to z_k$, we have $w\to 1/z_k$ and $u\to0$. This function has an obvious essential singularity at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Laurent series of $\tan\left( \frac{1}{z} \right) $ around $z_k$ is
$$ \tan\left( \frac{1}{z} \right) = \frac{1/z_k^2}{z - z_k} + h_k(z) $$
where $h_k(z)$ is holomorphic around $z_k$. Then $g$ around $z_k$ takes the form
$$ g(z) = \exp\left( \frac{1/z_k^2}{z - z_k} \right) \cdot \exp\left( h_k(z) \right)$$
where the second factor is holomorphic and the first factor clearly has a